# Binding to sibling elements

Tags: templates, polymer

I see that directly binding to sibling elements is no longer supported - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#binding-to-sibling-elements

The suggested approach for 1.0 works for properties but what about binding directly to the sibling element itself, for example:

```
<template>
  <x-publisher id="publisher"></x-publisher>
  <x-subscriber publisher="{{$.publisher}}"></x-subscriber>
</template>
```

I used this in 0.5 to access **methods** of the sibling element as well as properties. Is there any way to do this in 1.0? And generally is this bad practice?

**Update**

Based on Vartan's comment I took a look at iron-meta & seems you can do something like this in the x-publisher definition:

```
new Polymer.IronMeta({key: 'publisher', value: this});
```

Then in the x-subscriber definition you can do:

```
this.publisher = (new Polymer.IronMeta()).byKey('publisher');
```

However you don't get the benefits of the binding system with this - for example you can't use the observers array to observe path based property changes to the publisher object. You could setup an object observer directly but starts to become quite a bit messier than the old 0.5 way of binding directly to siblings.

Understood if this is just part of the performance tradeoff, but want to confirm there's not a better way! Also would be nice to know if binding to the full element is generally a performance issue anyways.

Comment: This is not something you would want to do (at least not in this fashion) in 1.0. Instead, take a look at [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta), which is the preferred way in 1.0 to share information/methods across your DOM tree. It's the same pattern used by [iron-validator-behavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-validator-behavior) to allow you to instantiate a data validator somewhere in your element/app and use its functionality elsewhere by pointing to it with the respective property.

Comment: Also note that similar to the iron-meta approach you could add a 'self' property to the x-publisher element that references its 'this' object, then use the 'self' property to do the binding. Not sure of the performance ramifications of binding to an entire element though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<template>
  <x-publisher id="publisher"></x-publisher>
  <x-subscriber publisher="{{getElement('publisher')}}"></x-subscriber>
</template>
...
getElement: function(name) { return this.$[name]; }
```

Comment: sweet, thanks. However the bindings don't seem to be set up right. In x-subscriber any use of {{publisher.property}} isn't updated on changes to x-publishers properties, nor are any manually configured observers. Is this a bug?

Comment: You cannot pass an element through and expect it's bindings to work in the alternate scope, this is not a bug. `x-subscriber` has no way of automatically listening to `publisher`'s update events.

Comment: Ok makes sense when I think it through, thank you. Just double checked & in 0.5 we could not use declarative bindings here either, ie {{publisher.property}}, but we could set up an 'observe' object for the passed in element properties. Would be great if that were still available, I found it very useful. However guessing it might require something like Object.observe which is no longer used?